# "Da-" and "wo-" compounds of German

Tags: etymology

- *Whereof, thereof, hereof*
- *whither, thither, hither*
- *wherefrom, therefrom, herefrom*
- *wherewith, therewith, herewith*.

Are these related to German *da-* and *wo-* compounds?

Comment: Yes. Both languages' terms are historically related; they both come from the PIE interrogative root [_*kʷo-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080804223658/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE258.html) and the demonstrative root [_*to-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628043014/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE534.html). In English, PIE *t became 'th', and PIE *kʷ became 'wh'; but in Latin they stayed and became 'qu' and 't', as in _quantum/tantum, qualis/talis_. In Greek *to stayed, too, becoming the masculine article, but labiodentals like *kʷ got smeared all over the chart.

Comment: Jeez! I was about to ask exactly the same question...

Answer (score 2):

*OED 1* treats constructions of this sort s.v **Here**, *adv.*  16. **Here- in combination with adverbs and prepositions*

> These originated, as in the other Teutonic languages, in the juxtaposition of *here* and another adv. Qualifying the same verb. Thus, in HEREBEFORE, 1st quot. *hǽr beforan* = here (in this document), before (i. e. at an earlier place). Cf. *hereinbefore, hereinafter, in which *herein* is similarly used. But as many advs. were identical in form with prepositions, and there was little or no practical difference between ‘here, at an earlier place’ and ‘before or at an earlier place than this’, the adv. came to be felt as a prep. governing *here* (=this place); and, on the analogy of this, new combinations were freely formed of *here* (*there*, *where*) with prepositions which had never been adverbs, as *herefor*, *hereto*, *hereon*, *herewith*.

That suggests to me that the German and English constructions are independent but parallel due to their syntactic similarity.

*Hither*, *thither*, *whither* however are independent words, not compounds; they are variously derived and have influenced each other before reaching the 'modern' forms.

Comment: I used to use this as an [example of a _paradigm_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html) in my Intro class.

Comment: @JohnLawler And I thought I was just putting in two cents' worth!